# Merge rows with same column value into 1 - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table looking like this:

```
+--+--+------+
|DB|NR|Amount|
+--+--+------+
|BE|10|20    |
+--+--+------+
|BE|10|30    |
+--+--+------+
|FR|20|50    |
+--+--+------+
|FR|20|10    |
+--+--+------+
|DE|30|25    |
+--+--+------+
|BE|35|75    |
+--+--+------+
```

Which query do I need to use to merge all the rows with the same DB and NR?

This should be the result:

```
+--+--+------+
|DB|NR|Amount|
+--+--+------+
|BE|10|50    |
+--+--+------+
|FR|20|60    |
+--+--+------+
|DE|30|25    |
+--+--+------+
|BE|35|75    |
+--+--+------+
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`try this`

```
select DB,NR,sum(amount) from table group by NR,DB
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
  select DB,NR, SUM(Amount) 
    from table
    group by DB,NR
```